# Why am I getting an empty array with (scrapy shell response.xpath())?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm wondering why response.xpath() returns an empty array `[]` in [this page](https://www.amazon.cn/b/2127529051), even if I do `response.xpath('//div').extract()`!
Example:

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.amazon.cn/b/2127529051
...
>>> response.xpath('//div').extract()
[]
```

I can get some results from the homepage, but I can't get any results from many other pages.

BTW, *I'm not trying crawling amazon or something, it's just for learning purposes only.*

I tried other sites as well, but didn't face this issue, so I want to know why.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

- response.xpath('\div').execute()
- there can be only few reason for this

  1. User agent : `scrapy shell site name  -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36'`
  2. your response is empty,try just response. It shows 200-300 then its okay
  3. path is wrong as per the site

this should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

> `response.xpath('\\div').execute()`

This line is just wrong. First of all you use front-slashes instead of back-slashes here. Also `execute()` is not a method of `Selector` or `SelectorList` objects (those are the values that are returned by response.xpath() method).

Try: `response.xpath("//div").extract()`

Other than your code being broken it's a good practice to turn off javascript and run `view(response)` to see exactly what your spider is seeing. In some cases your spider might not even see `"//div[@id='name']"` because it's loaded in with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually the code I used is correct although it is not in this question. I actually used `response.xpath("//div").extract()`, I just missed the code up here as I was filling the question in a hurry. I'll try `view(response)`.

Comment: I've tried: `scrapy shell https://www.amazon.cn/b/2127529051` and `response.xpath("//div").extract()` found me `605` items.

Make sure you are not blocked. Look at `response` with `view(response)` and check `response.status` to see if you are getting `200`.

Comment: I got `301` for `response.status`, and an empty page for `view(response)`

Comment: @XO39 right, 301 means that the page has moved somewhere else. Scrapy is smart enough to redirect you automatically unless you have Redirect Middleware disabled on your project or something. For me it redirects to: `https://www.amazon.cn/b?ie=UTF8&node=2127529051`. Not sure why amazon does this but my guess would be - it checks if your ip is not from china and if so redirect to utf8 encoded page instead of whatever default is.

So you need to figure out why your scrapy or scrapy project's redirect is disabled.

Comment: Check out [this doc for more info on redirect middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html?highlight=redirect%20middleware#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect)